# Does the native executable that is created by graalvm compiler includes memory management and GC?

Tags: java, jvm, garbage-collection, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I have been exploring graalvm and couldnt find an answer for this. Since the native executable that is created by graalvm compiler can run on any VM without Graalvm or JVM, what takes care of the memory management and GC? Does the native executable that is created by graalvm compiler includes memory management, GC an other things required during runtime?

Couldn't find a clear explanation for this in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the GC also works in applications packaged with `native-image`. This is explained in the [Memory Management](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/optimizations-and-performance/MemoryManagement/) section of the docs.

The GC will still manage objects created by the application. However, `native-image` might perform optimizations so that some objects are allocated on the stack or freed immediately when they aren't needed any more if it is able to detect that.

You can even select a GC using the `--gc` argument to `native-image`. You can use the following GCs:

- **Serial GC**: This GC has minimal footprint but only uses a single thread for garbage collection and might pause the application during that. It is also the default GC for normal Java applications (not native-image) with small heap sizes and it is the default for applications packaged with `native-image`.
- **G1**: The G1 GC optimizes for throughput, uses multiple threads and has lower pause times than Serial GC. It is the default GC for normal Java applications (not native-image) that don't have small heap sizes. This GC is only available if you are using Oracle GraalVM, it doesn't work with GraalVM Community Edition.
- **Epsilon**: The Epsilon GC doesn't do any garbage collection. If memory is full, the application will crash. This might be useful for testing, if you have small scripts that don't need any garbage collection or have a real-time application that can afford to restart regularly to avoid GC pauses or similar.

There is also work on making ZGC available on native-image.